# DropWizard app cannot be accessed from outside Docker

Tags: docker, dropwizard

I have a DropWizard application which I'm trying to run inside a Docker.

I'm using the following command.

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/app -t --expose 8080 -p 8080:8080 openjdk bash -c "cd app && java -jar build/libs/app.jar server infrastructure/config/config.yml"
```

but when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/swagger/ui` I get a `localhost refused to connect.` error.

But if I used the following command to go inside the docker first and then run the dropwizard application from there and then `wget` from inside the application, I can see the application is really running. But i still can't access it from outside the Docker.

```
docker run -i -v `pwd`:/app -t --expose 8080 -p 8080:8080 openjdk bash
```

then

```
root@06a1c2648236:/# cd app && java -jar build/libs/app.jar server infrastructure/config/config.yml &
```

then

```
wget localhost:8080
```

This means the application is running in the container, but I can't access it outside from the container.

Comment: I didn't see the expose flag used together with the publish flag. Can you try running without the `--expose 8080`. I'm thinking this may be prioritized over the publish flag

Comment: I tried running without the `--expose 8080`, but it is still the same :/

Comment: Are other endpoints working? Seems you may be running your containers on a docker-machine. What does `docker-machine ls` output? Does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` output anything?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, thus not using `docker-machine`.

Comment: Alright. Start the container. Run `docker ps` and note the container id. What is the output of running `docker inspect --format '{{json (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8080/tcp" 0 "HostIp") }}' <replace_with_container_id>`?

Comment: That is "0.0.0.0"